# Angular Controller access in jQuery with ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

I'm working on a mobile app with Ionic and Angular and my new template also uses jQuery.

All of my app works very well, the only trouble I am having is with jQuery ajax when I call a dynamic page, with all my dependencies, I can't access to all my Angular functions and controllers.

Example, I have index.html with all my dependencies, all my angular {{variable}} are working fine for index.html but when I call dynamically menu.html which is with jQuery for a special animation, the page works, all the dependencies are included but my angular controllers and variables are not working.

For example I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined" for my var {{i18n.app.slogan}}

So this menu.html does not have access to my angular controller and variables but all the dependencies are included, no other error.

Could it be a DOM issue or a listener issue? As I also work with Framework7 but it's causing trouble, I absolutely don't know what is the problem.

Thank you

John

Comment: What do you mean by: "but when I call dynamically menu.html wich is with jQuery". Why are you doing this with jQuery? How are you doing this?

Comment: Hi, the script is done like that, what I mean by "call dynamically" is that when I click on my menu icon, the page is called with a router like: localhost:8100/#!/index.html or localhost:8100/#!/templates/menu.html So menu.html is call through jQuery Ajax, the script is made like that, so when I'm on index.html all is good but on menu.html no access to my functions but on the source or network all my dependencies are here. It's like the DOM was not read or something like that or the functions are not loaded.

Comment: why on earth you would do such a horrible thing? build your router using angular and only angular and it will work.

Comment: The script I'm using has been made like that, normally it's a Framework7 and jQuery script, but as my app is with Ionic + Angular, I wanted to adapt because the animations for the links from the script are good and the script is well coded.

So I put my Angular + Ionic, it's working for all my direct pages but not for my dynamic pages.

That's why I was trying to figure out why even with all the dependencies and all my html tags my Angular Controllers wouldn't work.

That's it because the script is working very well.

Comment: So what could be the solution if I want jQuery and AngularJs?